# Mean Reputation Change

Tags: code-golf, stack-exchange-api

## Challenge

Given a the ID for a PPCG user who has existed for at least a month, output the average amount of reputation they gain per month. You can do this by dividing their reputation by the time since their account was created (which you can find on the profile). This should be returned floored; that is, truncate all of the decimals. (We don't care about the small stuff).

## Input

A single integer, which is the user's ID

## Output

A single integer, representing the floored rep change per month.

## Test Cases

```
input -> output
42649 -> 127 (me)
12012 -> 3475 (Dennis)
8478  -> 3015 (Martin Ender)
```

Comment: Can you define what a month is considered to be - a calendar month, a lunar month or 30 days? Or is it at our discretion?

Comment: @Shaggy When you go to a user profile, under the profile tab, it says "User for <x time>". Go by that.

Comment: @HyperNeutrino so the formula is `(rep/daysSinceAccountCreate)*30`? You need to give us a constant for what a month is.

Comment: @Sirens Go [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42649/hyper-neutrino?tab=profile) and Ctrl-F for `1 year, 9 months`. That's what I mean.

Comment: Should a check that the user has existed for at least a month be included?

Comment: @DimP I will say you can assume that.

Answer (score 2):

## JS, ES6 <s>243</s> <s>235</s> <s>168</s> <s>166</s> <s>165</s> 164 bytes

```
i=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/users/${i}?site=codegolf`).then(x=>x.json()).then(x=>alert(~~((y=x.items[0]).reputation/((new Date/1e3-y.creation_date)/2592e3))))
```

Based on [the Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/121370/58826).

Run this in the console:

```
(i=>fetch(`//api.stackexchange.com/users/${i}?site=codegolf`).then(x=>x.json()).then(x=>alert(~~((y=x.items[0]).reputation/((new Date/1e3-y.creation_date)/2592e3)))))(+prompt("Enter a userId"))
```

-4 thanks to [@insert_name_here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59682/insert-name-here)

#### Old answer:

```
z=>fetch("//codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/"+z).then(x=>x.text()).then(x=>alert((/([\d,]+) <span class="label-uppercase">repu/.exec(x)[1].replace(/,/g,"")/(((y=/Member for <.+>((\d+) years?, )?(\d+) month/.exec(x))[2]||0)*12+ +y[3]||0))))
```

Improvements welcome! Just fetches the profile page and parses it with regular expressions!

Won't work as a stack snippet, but you can paste this in your console:

```
(z=>fetch("//codegolf.stackexchange.com/u/"+z).then(x=>x.text()).then(x=>alert(Math.floor(/([\d,]+) <span class="label-uppercase">repu/.exec(x)[1].replace(/,/g,"")/(((y=/Member for <.+>((\d+) years?, )?(\d+) month/.exec(x))[2]||0)*12+ +y[3]||0)))))(+prompt("Enter a userId"))
```

Comment: Okay :) You have a much higher rep change than me D: I think about double

Comment: You could save two bytes by using `new Date` instead of `Date.now()`. You could also save one more by using `1e3` instead of `1000` and another by using `2592e3` instead of `2592000`.

Answer (score 1):

### Python <s>3</s> 2, <s>206</s> <s>219</s> <s>201</s> 193 bytes

```
import requests,time
a=requests.get('http://api.stackexchange.com/users/'+str(input())+'?site=codegolf').json()['items'][0]
print a['reputation']/((int(time.time())-a['creation_date'])/2592000)
```

I am estimating the months as the OP suggested, but actually `print(int(b/((d-c)/2592000)))` is a more accurate solution than `print(int(b/int((d-c)/2592000)))` and also saves a few bytes.

Comment: `get` is not defined

Comment: @HyperNeutrino try it again now, should work (Python 2). Obviously needs `requests`.