# Race for the Steward Badge

Tags: code-golf, internet, stack-exchange-api

#### Backstory

If you visit the [Steward Badge Page](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/badges/81/steward), you will see no one has received one of these badges from PPCG yet. However, there are two users:
**[DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem)** & **[Martin Ender](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/8478/martin-ender)**, that are only a few reviews away from this badge!

#### Challenge

Your challenge is to write a program or function that when run outputs DJMcMayhem's review count from the [Low Quality](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats) reviews & Martin Ender's review count from [First Posts](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/stats) reviews.

Your code needs to be dynamic so you should not hard-code the values of the current count. You should actually go and fetch the counts from those pages.

Your output should be the user's name and the count, with some delimiter in between each value, and there is no input.

#### Examples

```
DJMcMayhem, Count] [Martin Ender, Count]
 
DJMcMayhem, Count, Martin Ender, Count
 
DJMcMayhem Count Martin Ender Count
 
DJMcMayhem
Count
Martin Ender
Count

etc.....
```

No extraneous info is allowed.

#### Rules

[Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are not allowed.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes for each language wins!

<sup>[Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/15034/76365)</sup>

Comment: Interesting challenge. Just a heads up, 22 hours in the Sandbox is quite short. The recommended time is 72 hours, so that many people can see and offer criticism.

Comment: How does this challenge make sense in the context of [this standard loophole](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1062/16484)?

Comment: @Nit standard loopholes don’t have to be disallowed

Comment: I’ve casted my vote to close this question as a duplicate because it is a [tag:stack-exchange-api] challenge involving and comparing 2 users, just like the other challenge. In my opinion, the only difference is looking at a badge progess rather than the reputation, and moreover the post I linked to has looser I/O rules.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder, I looked for reviews in the API but couldn't find them so I'd argue against that dupe target. We have had a couple of challenges that required scraping data from an SE page, though; one of those would probably be a better target.

Comment: [Very related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119050/mean-reputation-change); potentially duplicate. Also requires scraping an SE webpage (though with ID input not hardcode). I can't vote though because it is binding.

Comment: @dylnan Yeah, but the challenge text says all of them are disallowed.

Comment: `Awarded 1 time: DJMcMayhem`

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 259 bytes

```
c:"https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/review/"t: copy c
d:"low-quality-posts/stats"e:"first-posts/stats"
f: func[s q][parse find s q[thru{-count">^M^/}any" "copy n to" "(print[q n])]]
f read to-url append c d"DJMcMayhem"
f read to-url append t e"Martin Ender"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bU09T8MwEN3zK043wZB698AEC1IWVsuVrPO5sUhtxz7TRhW/PURsSGzv@1X2@wd7MHYnjbNIaVopyp4veQmnJo4@@U6zSxc@Ub6qyl@RbwpFA@WyAQ1e45Jv49rdEmUbS27S1FGUhqwxxNrkjzgEDaEnMg1Wa4qrjSHE5OHgRubaHyPlngRfztNZfbu0IeDvVwLJB34qNSYxKyT7bO0QoLLzhzX2uoArhY8tAo@v7xNNbpv5iv@HBBgnVyUmeEueK@77Dw)

Unfortunately doesn't work in TIO - results in timeout, although works normally in Red console.